# PHP array_push doesn't work with jquery $_REQUEST object

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-droppable, array-push

At http://maureenmoore.com/momp_112412/112412.html I am trying to make an array of the divs that were dragged into the droppable box. Please see the view source.

I use $.post to send the divs to the php file process.php and it gives me 1 to 3 arrays depending on how many divs I dragged instead of just one combined array. I want to push the $_REQUEST object (i.e., the dropped div) into an array using

```
$stack = array();
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
            array_push($stack,$value);
          }
print_r($stack);
```

but it gives me 1 to 3 arrays each with the key of zero. How do I get one array out of for example 3 dragged divs?

#### Code ported from link:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#draggable1" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ] });
  $( "#draggable2" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ] });
  $( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ] });     

  $( "#droppable_box" ).droppable({                
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
       var data = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
       $("#response").append(data);
       $('#myId').click(function(event){
         $.post("process.php",({id : data}),function(data,status){  
          alert("Data: " + data);
         });
       });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: The keys of `$stack` should be numbered from zero to the size of `$_REQUEST` - 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why your code would give identical keys in `$stack`, but you could rewrite your code to this one-liner:

```
$stack = array_values($_REQUEST);
```

Btw, making a blind copy of `$_REQUEST` doesn't seem all that useful :)

**Update**

You've added your JavaScript now; this code:

```
$('#myId').click(function(event){
     $.post("process.php",({id : data}),function(data,status){  
      alert("Data: " + data);
     });
   });
```

Should be placed outside of your `.droppable()` declaration.

Comment: Thanks but I don't get any alerts at all if I place it outside the droppable declaration. Also $stack = array_values($_REQUEST); didn't give me the right array either.

Comment: @maureenmoore okay I know why, but I can only answer you in about 10 hours :)

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the click inside the drop function, binding three times if three drops are made, and firing off three ajax requests etc.

It needs to be more like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    $("#draggable1").draggable({ grid: [20, 20] });
    $("#draggable2").draggable({ grid: [20, 20] });
    $("#draggable3").draggable({ grid: [20, 20] });

    $("#droppable_box").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            data.push($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
            $("#response").append($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        }
    });

    $('#myId').click(function(event) {
        $.post("/echo/html/", ({ id: data }), function(return_data, status) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});​
```

on the serverside you'd get that with `$_POST['id'];`

Comment: When I pasted the code above over my original jquery I couldn't drag the draggable divs any more but thanks anyway.

Comment: @MaureenMoore - seems to work fine for me, here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DmSdq/)

Comment: @MaureenMoore - Also, if you're looking for an array on the serverside, you'll have to create an array to be sent on the clientside. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: The winning answer is from adeneo. You can view the correct view source here: http://maureenmoore.com/momp_112412/121712_1400.html